# How to create multiple 3D face without reference with a script

Tags: modeling, scripting

I am looking for a way to create a multiple but different 3D face using script in Blender to be used for my machine learning dataset. At first I thought of using facebuilder addon to do it but it requires a lot of image reference and human action to pin the reference image's nose, eye , ear, chin position, making it hard to automate in a script. So I was hoping that someone can help giving me direction/guide on doing this since most of the google post I found are using reference image just like facebuilder. Below is the example that I want to recreate and the modification I am looking for are for example changing randomly the eye color, jawbone length, gender, skin color and etc just like a character creation in games. So far I have tried to use the addon to learn the code info and create a basic object using script but don't know how to create a suitable texture of it. Thank you in advance

[image: sample]

Comment: Hi, could you show us what you have tried and where you are stuck ?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: hello, so far I have tried using the facebuilder addon but stuck on how to automate /script the pinning process since it requires human intervention and also finding lots of suitable picture is also a challenge